# Apache2 Django NameError: name "TypeError" is not defined

Tags: django, apache2, vps

I am trying to run a django application on VPS via apache2, but I get the following in the website-error file, also 400(Bad Request):

```
Exception ignored in: <function Local.__del__ at 0x7f47273f48b0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/asgiref/local.py", line 96, in __del__
NameError: name 'TypeError' is not defined
```

I successfully ran a simple website that was made with "django-admin startproject" and could be viewed, but uploading project, made with the following skeleton, produces this error: https://django-project-skeleton.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apache2_vhost.html

I have tried including the python site-packages in the WSGIDaemon and by exluding them it produces the same effect.

In addition to this, I have also added:

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>
```

But again, no change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this post was upvoted and maybe it can help the others searching for that problem: this is my `website.conf`, just change example to your domain name. It also redirects to your https version of the website:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
    
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>    
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
    # Insert the full path to the wsgi.py-file here
    WSGIScriptAlias /   /var/www/example/example/wsgi.py
   
    Alias /static/ /var/www/example/run/static/
    Alias /media/ /var/www/example/run/media/
 
    WSGIDaemonProcess   example python-path=/var/www/example

    # PROCESS_GROUP specifies a distinct name for the process group
    WSGIProcessGroup    example
    
    <Directory /var/www/example/example>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>
  
    <Directory /var/www/example/run/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/example/run/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    LogLevel info

    ErrorLog    ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example_error.log
    CustomLog   ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example_access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /var/ssl/example.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/ssl/example.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/ssl/example.ca-bundle

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: When i followed your conf, it was fine, I thought my errors gone, but unfortunately after two times restarting apache, same error is being faced, though your config is followed as it is. Did you try seeing log after apache restart

Answer (score 1):

Open your apache configuration's file then add "**LogLevel info**" inside the tag : **VirtualHost** at the end (before closing tag). It's works for me

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same (ignored) exception in my apache2 error logs while running a functional application. It seems like you're using WSGI, so this ASGI-related python package shouldn't be the cause of your 400 error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32426461)